# How can I input utf-8 symbols in telnet client on OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, telnet, utf-8

I am using OSX 10.6.8 and telnet via terminal. I can input russian (utf8) symbols in terminal, but when i use telnet, i can see russian symbols, but cannot input them (instead of "тест" i get "Q^BP5Q^AQ^B" for example).

How can i fix that? Should I put something in ~/.telnetrc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet is used to connect to a shell-session on a **remote** host, you need to configure the **remote** hosts's shell to expect UTF-8. This is usually done by setting an environment variable ate the **remote** end. The exact details depend on the operating system and shell at the **remote** host. Here's one example:

```
export LANG=ru_RU.utf8
```

If the **remote** host is Linux, use `locale -a` inside the telnet session to get a list of supported values for this setting at the **remote** host.

Comment: I already got export LANG=ru
export LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf-8
in my ~/.bash_login - it allows me to input russian text in the terminal, but when i start telnet, input becomes broken

Comment: it seems to me like it has something to do with telnet encoding. In my question there is an example where i clearly input 4 utf8 symbols, but get 8 1-byte symbols. That's why my guess is that something should be in ~/.telnetrc

Comment: @DataGreed: try LANG=ru_RU.utf8 (I can't recall if LANG overrrides LC_ALL). You are doing this at the remote end, not the local end aren't you?

Comment: oh, i understood now. I am doing it on the local end. I have no access to configuring the remote server, but it supports UTF8 for sure. It returns text as utf, the problems start when i try to type smth in response

Comment: are you sure that typing one symbols and getting another is a remote issue?

Comment: @DataGreed: You can set LANG on the fly at the remote end just by typing (in ASCII) `export LANG=ru_RU.utf8` inside the telnet session. You can also  `vi ~/.bashrc` inside the telnet session to make this setting more permanent. The remote end is receiving multibyte UTF-8 characters, interpreting them as some single-byte encoding, finding some bytes are not printable characters and echoing them back using a notation that displays byte 0x02 as two ASCII characters "`^B`" (referring to Control+B often used on ASCII keyboards to transmit that byte value)

Comment: unfortunately i cannot do that, telnet server expects some other response from me and does not react to export LANG=ru_RU.utf8, it's something like a MUD game i believe

Comment: @DataGreed: You'll need to find out what encoding the MUD supports, you can then change your *local* encoding and input methods to match that. I'd guess a Russian MUD might support the KOI encoding rather than UTF-8 but I don't know anything about KOI.

Comment: The thing that it asks me for encoding at first, i select utf8 (tried on ultiple different servers), then i get readable symbols, but input is broken..

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The other end is not a bash shell, and definitely supports utf-8. I can see utf-8 symbols that it sends me. I could send utf-8 with other clients. I can enter them on the local terminal. But when I telnet and type, they end up as two ASCII characters.